# error in setup ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, reinstalling

I've just downloaded ubuntu 15.10 and I've burn it on USB then I begin to install it as known but always apears the message 'error detection' when i re-download it the message changed but didn't install the OS 
what is the wrong?

Comment: What did you use to create the USB, where does this error occur, and what does the error change to?

Comment: I've used unetbootin-windows-613 for the USB

Comment: Try out [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie) and see if it helps.

Comment: the error occurred when i started to boot it and the error says "that there is no OS"

Answer (score 0):

You should Probably start over again  by downloading Ubuntu [Here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) Make Sure Your USB Is over 1.9 Gb. Then, Download Rufus [Here](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) 
Next, Proceed to Write the image iso to The disk. When completed You should get a notification saying "you can now boot ubuntu  on other pc's" or something of the sort. then just boot from the usb.